# Terminate a console application in Java

Tags: java

Is there a command that terminates a console application, something like: System.exit(0) as we have in Swing? Thanks.

S.

Comment: What are you attempting to do - force a running (hung) application to close, or just 'exit' after being done with whatever you were doing?

Answer (score 14):

`System.exit(0)` works the same.

Comment: Well, yes, but you shouldn't really be using it in either case (to exit an application); it terminates the entire VM, per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Comment: @X-Zero yes, but the OP seem to be confusing the `System.exit(0)` as Swing only; I just tried to clarify that it works in console applications too.